# Documenting properties in KDoc

Tags: kotlin, kdoc

I see much code, which uses the tag `@property` to document properties:

```kotlin
/**
 * Some Class
 *
 * @property p Some property
 */
class C {
  val p = 42
}
```

But I prefer to document properties where the are defined:

```kotlin
/** Some Class */
class C {
  /** Some property */
  val p = 42
}
```

Are the two ways equivalent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [Document Kotlin code](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/kotlin-doc.html):

```kotlin
/**
 * A group of *members*.
 *
 * This class has no useful logic; it's just a documentation example.
 *
 * @param T the type of a member in this group.
 * @property name the name of this group.
 * @constructor Creates an empty group.
 */
class Group<T>(val name: String) {
    /**
     * Adds a [member] to this group.
     * @return the new size of the group.
     */
    fun add(member: T): Int { ... }
}
```

There, they explain the purpose of the `@property` like this:

> *Documents the property of a class which has the specified name. This tag can be used for documenting properties declared in the primary constructor, where putting a doc comment directly before the property definition would be awkward.*

Thus, your way of doing (second example in your question) is the proper way to go in KDoc. The only place where `@property` makes sense is for primary constructor properties.

Note that even in constructor, we could get rid of the `@property` and write instead:

```kotlin
/**
 * ...
 */
class Group<T>(
  /** the name of this group. */
  val name: String
) {
    // ...
}
```

This last point is more a matter of taste. I personally never use `@property`, which looks to java-esque for my taste.